# How to input data to database with laravel and react native in mobile application?

Tags: laravel, database, react-native

I'm working with laravel and react native first time
I connected my database with laravel and can get data from it, but the problem is i can't input data in that database from my mobile application

this is my screen with reading data

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList,Alert,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import * as React from 'react';


const HomeScreen = ()=> {

  const [students, setStudents]=useState([])
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = React.useState(false);
  const onPress = () => Alert.alert("refreshing");


      const getAllStudent = async() =>{
        try{
          const students =await axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/student')
          console.log(students.data)
          setStudents(students.data)
        } catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
          
}
useEffect (() =>{
  getAllStudent()

},[])

const onRefresh=React.useCallback( async()=>{
 await getAllStudent();
})
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} >
      <FlatList
        
          data={students}
          key={(item) =>item.id}
          renderItem={({item})=><Text style={styles.textitem}>{item.stuname}{"\n"}{item.email}</Text>}
          
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
            refreshing={refreshing}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}

          
            />
          }

      />  

    
   </View>
  );
}
export default HomeScreen
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor:'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
  
  },

  textitem:{
    fontSize:20,
    color:'black',
    padding:20

  }
});
```

this is my screen with input data

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,FlatList,Alert,TouchableOpacity,TextInput } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


const TaskView = () => {
  const [students, setStudents]=useState({
      stuname: '',
      email:''

  }); 

  const handleChange  = (name, value) => setStudents({...students, [name]:value });

  const handleSubmit =async () =>{
    
      try{
         axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/task')
        }
          catch(error){
     console.log(error)
         }  
        
  };
return (
        <View style={styles.View1}>
           
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                placeholder='Write a name'
                onChange={(text) => handleChange('stuname', text)}
            />
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                placeholder='Write a email'
                onChange={(text) => handleChange('email', text)}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonSave} onPress={handleSubmit}>
                     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save Task</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
)
}

export default TaskView
```

my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Student;
use  Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return Student::all();
    }
    
     function add(Request $request){
        
         $request -> validate([

            'stuname'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required'
         ]);

         $query = DB::table('students') -> insert([
            'stuname'=>$request ->input('stuname'),
            'email'=>$request ->input('email'),

         ]);
         }
}
```

and my api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;

Route::get('/student',[StudentController::class, 'index']);

Route::post('/task',[StudentController::class, 'add']);
```

I tried to find some info about that, but all i found is about laravel+rect laravel+vue
p.s. i use mysql
I need some knowledges how to do it but don't know where to find information or examples
when i run with npm start i have error:Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you posted you are not sending the data along the http post request to api/task.

the 422 status code you receive from laravel indicates a validation fail, it expects stuname and email and it receives nothing.

Comment: now i have other problem, idk how to connect my inputs from app in axios.post

i wrote this:

 axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/task', {
          stuname:'stuname',
          email:'email'
}

but now it just adding "stuname" and "email" into by db

Comment: you are hardcoding the values. you should get values from state, try{ stuname : students.stuname, email: students.email }